# How to limit users video uploads to 10 videos per week

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to limit the number of posts a user posts within a week on my worpress site.

My code only limit the total number of videos a user can upload but i want to limit it to just a week. Below is my code

```
<?php
function streamtube_child_check_limit_uploads( $errors ){
 
    $max_allowed                = 10;
 
    $current_user_total_posts   = count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), 'video' );
 
    // Check roles ... etc
    
    // This limitation should not apply to administrator and editor, maybe.
    
    if( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ){
        if( $current_user_total_posts > $max_allowed ){
            $errors->add(
                'not_allowed',
                esc_html__( 'You have reached the maximum allowed number of uploads.', 'streamtube-child' )
            );
        }        
    }
 
    return $errors;
 
}
add_filter( 'streamtube/core/upload/video/errors', 'streamtube_child_check_limit_uploads', 100, 1 );
add_filter( 'streamtube/core/upload_chunks/video/errors', 'streamtube_child_check_limit_uploads', 100, 1 );
add_filter( 'streamtube/core/post/import_embed/errors', 'streamtube_child_check_limit_uploads', 100, 1 );`
```

Comment: You are counting all posts, not limited to a time range.

Answer (score 0):

The standard [count_user_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/) function will not work since it simply gives you a post total for the user.

This answer using [wp_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) should work after adjusting for weeks: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70323/count-user-posts-by-type-and-date